# Calling into Haskell from multiple C/C++ threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, haskell, ffi

I have a small function in written Haskell with the following type:

```
foreign export ccall sget :: Ptr CInt -> CSize -> Ptr CSize -> IO (Ptr CInt)
```

I am calling this from multiple C++ threads running concurrently (via
TBB).  During this part of the execution of my program I can barely get a
load average above 1.4 even though I'm running on a six-core CPU (12
logical cores).  I therefore suspect that either the calls into Haskell all
get funnelled through a single thread, or there is some significant
synchronization going on.

I am not doing any such thing explicitly, all the function does is operate
on the incoming data (after storing it into a Data.Vector.Storable), and
return the result back as a newly allocated array (from Data.Marshal.Array).

Is there anything I need to do to fully enable concurrent calls like this?

I am using GHC 8.6.5 on Debian Linux (bullseye/testing), and I am compiling with -threaded -O2.

Looking forward to reading some advice,

Sebastian

Comment: *Update:* I found that adding runtime options `+RTS -N2 -RTS` gives an improvement. From the [Documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#ffi-threads) I would have thought this only affects _imported_ forgein functions, but perhaps what helps in this case is that it enables parallel garbace collection, as described [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-concurrent.html#parallel-options).  It's still not great, however, and also I find that using a number larger than 2 gives worse performance than `-N2`.

Comment: Was the Haskell program linked with `-threaded`? That's what's specified [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#ffi-threads).

Comment: Yes, for both compiling and linking I specify the `-threaded` option.

Answer (score 2):

Using the simple example at the end of this answer, if I compile with:

```sh
$ ghc -O2 Worker.hs
$ ghc -O2 -threaded Worker.o caller.c -lpthread -no-hs-main -o test
```

then running it with `./test` occupies only one core at 100%.  I need to run it with `./test +RTS -N`, and then on my 4-core desktop, it runs at 400% with a load average of around 4.0.

So, the RTS `-N` flag affects the number of parallel threads that can simultaneously run an exported Haskell function *and* there is no special action required (other than compiling with `-threaded` and running with `+RTS -n`) to fully utilize all available cores.

So, there must be *something* about your example that's causing the problem.  It could be contention between threads over some shared data structure.  Or, maybe parallel garbage collection is causing problems; I've observed parallel GC causing worse performance with increasing `-N` in a simple test case (details forgotten, sadly), so you could try turning off parallel GC with `-qg` or limiting the number of cores involved with `-qn2` or something.  To enable these options, you need to call `hs_init_with_rtsopts()` in place of the usual `hs_init()` as in my example.

If that doesn't work, I think you'll have to try to narrow down the problem and post a minimal example that illustrates the performance issue to get more help.

My example:

`caller.c`

```c
#include "HsFFI.h"
#include "Rts.h"
#include "Worker_stub.h"
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREAD 4

void*
work(void* arg)
{
        for (;;) {
                fibIO(30);
        }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        hs_init_with_rtsopts(&argc, &argv);

        pthread_t threads[NUM_THREAD];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; ++i) {
                int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, work, NULL);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; ++i) {
                pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        }

        hs_exit();
        return 0;
}
```

`Worker.hs`

```hs
module Worker where

import Foreign

fibIO :: Int -> IO Int
fibIO = return . fib

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n | n > 1 = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
      | otherwise = 1

foreign export ccall fibIO :: Int -> IO Int
```

Comment: I just tried `-qg`, but I only get this message in return: *Most RTS options are disabled. Use hs_init_with_rtsopts() to enable them.* That function is not declared in my HsFFI.h, though, and when I add a manual `extern void hs_init_with_rtsopts(int *argc, char **argv[]);` I get a linker error. Any advice what I need to do to make that work?

Comment: You should be able to `#include "Rts.h"` to get the definition, and I've updated the example with what worked for me.  But, what you did should have worked, too, and I can't understand why you got a linker error.

Comment: An alternative, using `hs_init_ghc`, is documented in the second code example in [this section](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#using-your-own-main) of the GHC documentation.

Comment: Okay, `#include "Rts.h"` solves it.  Probably my manual declaration gave the linker error because I should have written `extern "C" void ...`. Performance-wise, the combination `-N -qg` is a clear win -- thank you!